# router query parameter undefined but still displayable in HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I'm trying to write a page that takes the 'name' query parameter from the current URL, display it, and use it to make an API call later on.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

function Map(){

  const router = useRouter();
  var name = router.query.name;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The page correctly displays the name parameter in the HTMl which means the router query is working, but whenever I try to use or print the variable anywhere, it tells me it's undefined. I can't figure out why, especially since it's already used properly in the return statement. Would appreciate any insight on this.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use useState for this.

```
import { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

function Map(){

  const router = useRouter();
  var routerName = router.query.name;

  const [name, setName] = useState(routerName);

 useEffect(()=>{
   setName(routerName);
 }, [routerName] )

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem with both routerName and name printing as undefined, and I noticed useEffect never gets called...

Answer (score 0):

Using `react-router` you can do it. Write logic in `useEffect`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
function useQuery() {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
}
function Test() {
  const param = useQuery().get("name");
  const [name, setName] = useState(param);
  useEffect(() => {
    // Write logic here..
    param && setName(param);
  }, [param]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Test;
```

Comment: I'm getting "Cannot read property 'location' of undefined" from the useLocation().search line

Comment: u have to create router provider.. to use it

Answer (score 0):

In general, your function is **not correct** but if that works for you..!! Do the following steps:

import

```
import Router from 'next/router';
```

Instead of

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
```

Then your function would be like

```
function Map(){

  var name = Router.router.query.name;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```